# Upgrading patio supports

Tags: patio, beam

I have a patio roof that is sagging in one corner due to a poorly constructed slab. I am going to install 4 concrete columns 2 ft in the ground and 2 ft above with a post support mounted in the form. I am going to replace the existing beam and relocate about 10 inches further away from the house. By moving the beam further it will be lower to the ground due to the pitch of the roof. I don't want anyone to hit their head so I need to think of away minimize or eliminate a beam over the walkway to the backyard.

Is it possible to have 2 seperate beams instead of one continuous beam? I want there to be enough clearance through the walkway.

The joists are 11' 9" with 22" spacing. The beam is 28' and is 4x6.

I would like to remove the middle section over the walkway which is 8' or use sandwiched 2x4 for a 4x4 beam. I am going to use 4x4 posts.

[image: current back patio]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the code for frost line only 2' in you area ? The concrete columns need POST supports not beam supports. Column, post, beam.  Explain "*2 seperate beams instead of one continuous beam*" How is clearance through the walkway impacted by beams ? A more detailed explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You can have _100_ beams if you have 101 posts. I'm not clear on the question.

Comment: Use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to add new information. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Comment: The frost line is 12" in Arkansas.

Comment: So you want to take the center portion of the beam out and replace it with a 4x4 between the new posts? And you also move the posts further away from the building and increase the span that the joists cross between the building and the beam? I don't like either one, but together, it sounds like bad news. More information and/or more pictures would be very helpful. What is above? How long are the joists/rafters? How far apart are they? How long is the existing beam? How are they attached to the building?

Comment: I have added pictures and a better description to my earlier post. Thank you all for your interest.